# how can include <> ignore system default header file path(usr/include)?

Tags: c++, cmake, include

I have a c++ project where the build process is organized by cmakelist， the compile stuck at a point and prompt that g++ cannot find json/json.h, I check my standard header path(/usr/include) which indeed has this hearder file. after struggle for a while I found This project use header file from its own thirdparty directory(not /usr/include) and the include_directory path was incorrectly set by me!! This upset me How can it be realized since #include <> should firstly search standard header file path(/usr/include) !!??

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question completely but, the directories searched depend on both the compiler's configuration and the options passed on the command line.  `gcc`, for example, has the [`-nostdin`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html) option to prevent searching in the 'standard' system locations.

Answer (score 0):

This documentation
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/include 
Says about including with `""`
 
*"Typical implementations first search the directory where the current file resides and, only if the file is not found, search the standard include directories"*

I'm not certain I understand your question very well but,
if `json/json.h` is present in your local directories,
may be should you include this header-file with `""`?